# Can't connect Spring Cloud Vault to HCP Vault in Dev Mode Using Token Auth

Tags: spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

What I have:

- HCP Vault in Development mode
- Simple Spring Client using Spring Cloud Vault
- CLI Client

Desried Outcome:
Inject data into a variable using HCP Vault

What is working:

- Run Vault locally (in dev mode) and inject data into the variable
- Get the data from the HCP Vault using vault CLI

Notes:

- I'm generating the admin token to avoid the use of policies
- The secrets in HCP Vault and my local Vault are identical

This is my application.yml file:

```
spring.application.name: my-spring-boot-app


spring.cloud.vault:
  host: vault-cluster-public-vault-fjkdsahfdjksa.hfjksdfhdsajk.hashicorp.cloud
  port: 8200
  scheme: https
  authentication: TOKEN
  token: hvs.fdsjfhdsakjfhdasjkfhdasjkfhdasjkfhdasjkfhdasjkfhdasjkfhdsakj


spring.config.import: vault://

logging.level.org: INFO
logging.level.com: INFO
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @spencergibb, no. 

Now I created a token based on a policy.
`path "secret/data/my-spring-boot-app" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}`

I'm able to read the secret. But I created a REST request and got 403.
`curl \
    -H "X-Vault-Token: fjdskafjsakf-fjdskajfdsjakfsa-jfdksafjlaks" \
    -X GET \
    https://vault-cluster-public-vault-43267432.4732843.z1.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/secret/data/my-spring-boot-app`

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about what actually the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was missing the namespace header.

```
spring.cloud.vault:
  host: vault-cluster-public-vault-fjkdsahfdjksa.hfjksdfhdsajk.hashicorp.cloud
  port: 8200
  scheme: https
  namespace: admin
  authentication: TOKEN
  token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}
```

spring.config.import: vault://